# How to edit a PDF without incremental update?

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation

How to edit a PDF without incremental update? I want to change the text without any trace of editing and without being able to return to the old version. The file is not signed or protected. The PDF version is 1.4 the file was created by Apache FOP 1.0 but I don't have the XSL-FO file (I only have the XML file).

The incremental update in a visible way (in notepad ++) adds new objects and I don't know which old objects to replace with new ones (if possible). I would like the edited file to keep the original structure (created by Apache FOP 1.0) and the PDF version.

I can use a window application (Windows), console, website or something for C#

Comment: You can't. Even without an incremental update, if the number of bytes in the new object is different from the original, the xref table needs to change and then the fact that the two files are different will be obvious.

Comment: "without any trace" could you elaborate on what you mean exactly by this?